# Increase JVM heap size for Scala?

Tags: scala, command-line, jvm, heap-memory

I have a Scala data processing tool which is failing with a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception. The tool needs to make a couple passes over a large data file (the one I'm working on is over 700MB), so it would be convenient if the entire thing could be stored in memory.

I run the tool from the command line or from a Bash script using the "scala" runner. How do I increase the JVM heap size for this? I've tried passing `-Xmx1024m`, but it does not recognize this argument. I'm using a nightly build of Scala 2.8.0 (r18678).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The JAVA_OPTS environment variable is used to specify the options passed to the java command. See the [Scala manpage](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/manual/html/scala.html) for details.

Answer (score 124):

You can pass options to the JVM via -J.  E.g.,

```
scala -J-Xmx2g ...
```

Comment: Quick and easy solution, thank you! I wonder why the man page does not show this?

Answer (score 22):

Based on Joe's suggestion, I looked at the scala program, which is a Bash script that calls java with various Scala specific arguments. It allows extra command line arguments to be passed to Java through the JAVA_OPTS environment variable. So you can increase the heap size like this:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2g" scala classname arguments...
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit `JAVA_OPTS`.

Answer (score -1):

As a hack you can edit the `scala/bin/scala` file to edit the parameters for the `java` command. Not pretty.