# Scala linked list stackoverflow

Tags: scala, linked-list

Using scala I have added about 100000 nodes to a linked list.  When I use the function length, for example mylist.length.  I get a 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' error, is my list to big to process?  The list is only string objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears the library implementation is not tail-recursive `override def length: Int = if (isEmpty) 0 else next.length + 1`. It seems like this is something that could be discussed on the mailing list to check if an enhancement ticket should be opened.

You can compute the length like this:

```
def length[T](l:LinkedList[T], acc:Int=0): Int =
  if (l.isEmpty) acc else length(l.tail, acc + 1)
```

Comment: I'm all for an enhancement ticket. This method can be easily implemented in a non-recursive manner all the way back in `TraversableOnce`. I can even implement it in this comment line: `def length: Int = { var count = 0; foreach { _ => count += 1 }; count }`. Back on `LinearSeq`, it one can get even better performance by using a private helper method to make the original implementation fully tail recursive. IMHO, both approaches should be taken. Do you open it, or may I?

Comment: @Daniel Please open it, as you can provide more suggestions than me, just like you did here.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, computing the length of a List is an order n operation, therefore you should try to avoid it. You might consider switching to an Array, as that is a constant time operation.

Comment: `Vector` is preferable to `Array`

Answer (score 0):

You could try increasing the stack/heap size available to the JVM.

```
scala JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512M -Xms16M -Xss16M" MyClass.scala
```

Where

```
-Xss<size>  maximum native stack size for any thread
-Xms<size>  set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>  set maximum Java heap size
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441373/increase-jvm-heap-size-for-scala) has some more information.

See also this [This Scala document](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/tools/scala.html).

Comment: You mean `JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512M -Xms16M -Xss16M" scala MyClass.scala`? My shell requires for JAVA_OPTS to be before the scala command.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you truly need to use the `length` method?  It sounds like you might not be using the correct collection type for your use-case (hard to tell without any extra information).  Lists are optimised to be mapped over using folds or a tail-recursive function.

Despite saying that, this is absolutely an oversight that can easily be fixed in the standard library with a tail-recursive function.  Hopefully we can get it in time for 2.9.0.