# How can I increase the JVM heapsize for sbt run under Windows?

Tags: windows, scala, jvm, sbt, heap-memory

I have looked into related answers, but they are all Unix and all full configuration.

Currently if I need more heap I run my app as this from a batch file:

```
call scala -J-Xmx1200m -cp target\scala-2.11\classes Start
```

Can I do the same with sbt run, using light configuration?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441373/increase-jvm-heap-size-for-scala

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on Ardi Goxhaj's comment the batch file that works:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1200m
call sbt run
```