# Read from GZIPInputStream to String without using Source

Tags: scala, file

I am using Scala. I need to read a large gzip file and turn it into string. And I need to remove the first line.
This is how I read the file:

```
val fis = new FileInputStream(filename)
val gz  = new GZIPInputStream(fis)
```

And then I tried with this `Source.fromInputStream(gz).getLines.drop(1).mkString("")`
. But it causes out of memory error.

Therefore, I think of reading line by line and maybe put it into byte array. Then I can just convert it into a single String in the end.

But I have no idea how to do this. Any suggestion? Or any better method is also welcome.

Comment: Look into memory mapped IO. Also, a StringBuffer could probably help.

Comment: The OOM you are getting is because the contents of the file does not fit in memory. If does not matter if you read it into an array, a list or whatever other container. You either need more memory, or to think of a way to do what you need without getting the entire content into memory.

Comment: How big is the file when it is `gunzip`ed?

Comment: @dkim around 250MB

Comment: It might be helpful to check the maximum JVM heap size and, if necessary, increase it. Refer to 1) [How is the default java heap size determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13871564/234658) and 2) [Increase JVM heap size for Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1441373/234658).

Answer (score 2):

If your gzipped file is huge, you can go with [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). Here is an example. It copies all chars from gzipped file to uncompressed, but it **skips the first line**.

```
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream
import java.io._
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.util.Try

val bufferSize = 4096
val pathToGzFile = "/tmp/text.txt.gz"
val pathToOutputFile = "/tmp/text_without_first_line.txt"
val charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8

val inStream = new FileInputStream(pathToGzFile)
val outStream = new FileOutputStream(pathToOutputFile)

try {
  val inGzipStream = new GZIPInputStream(inStream)
  val inReader = new InputStreamReader(inGzipStream, charset)
  val outWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream, charset)
  val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inReader)

  val closeables =  Array[Closeable](inGzipStream, inReader, 
    outWriter, bufferedReader)
  // Read first line, so copy method will not get this - it will be skipped
  val firstLine = bufferedReader.readLine()
  println(s"First line: $firstLine")

  @tailrec
  def copy(in: Reader, out: Writer, buffer: Array[Char]): Unit = {
    // Copy while it's not end of file
    val readChars = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)
    if (readChars > 0) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, readChars)
      copy(in, out, buffer)
    }
  }

  // Copy chars from bufferReader to outWriter using buffer
  copy(bufferedReader, outWriter, Array.ofDim[Char](bufferSize))

  // Close all closeabes
  closeables.foreach(c => Try(c.close()))
}
finally {
  Try(inStream.close())
  Try(outStream.close())
}
```