# setting JVM heap size from sbt Console in IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, command-line, sbt

I get this error when running my app in intelliJ:

```
[error] (ABCThread-1) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Therefore, I am trying to set the heap size when i run my scala app from SBT Console / SBT Action:

I use the following : 
found here:
[Increase JVM heap size for Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441373/increase-jvm-heap-size-for-scala)

However i get the error:

```
scala>  -J-Xmx2g
<console>:12: error: object - is not a member of package scala
       scala -J-Xmx2g
             ^
<console>:12: error: not found: value J
       scala -J-Xmx2g
              ^
<console>:12: error: not found: value Xmx2g
       scala -J-Xmx2g
                ^
```

any idea? thnks

Comment: set SBT_OPTS may help for example  `export SBT_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=768m -Xss16m`

Comment: @shengshanzhang i get this error : `<console>:13: error: not found: value export                                                                                                                    
       export SBT_OPTS`   same thing if i use `set SBT_OPTS`  I get  `<console>:13: error: not found: value set                                                                                                                    
       set SBT_OPTS`

Comment: I tried setting SBT_OPTS in the environment variable and it worked like charm for me:
SBT_OPTS: -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=768m -Xss16m

.From Intellij, you can follow the documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html

Answer (score 7):

[image: where you should input the VM paramer]

the position is where you should input the VM parameters if you use IDEA

Comment: do you set fork := true in the sbt shell ?

Comment: i am using the sbt Console - the sbt Shell gives me some dependencies errors - So, in the sbt Console, no iam not using `set fork := true`

Comment: actually set and export are not part of the commands available to sbt Console

Answer (score 0):

1.Edit the VM Options field in the run/debug configuration of the app that
you start. vmoptions file adjusts the memory used by IntelliJ, If I am not wrong, you
are having a shortage of memory of JRE that is launched by IntelliJ to execute your app. Adjust the memory setting in VM options part of the Run/Debug configuration,for eg:https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U65i.jpg
[config setting](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties)

2.If step-1 not solved your problem switch to 64-bit JDK for IntelliJ IDEA if you are not using currently.

Comment: thanks i am using the 64-bit JDK but I tried option 1 before but not working either.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `IntelliJ preferences > Build,Execution,Deployement > compiler`. You'll find an option to set heap size as `Build process heap size(Mbytes):`. Change it to some higher value. It may solve the issue.